# OSGI ServiceTracker and thread-safety

Tags: thread-safety, osgi

ServiceTracker is defined as a Thread-Safe class in the OSGI 4.2 spec

The usage of this class is pretty straight forward.

Most of the examples employing ServiceTracker I could find on the internet show a snippet of code like the following:

```
ServiceInterface serviceObj = (ServiceInterface) serviceTracker.get();
if(serviceObj != null) {
  // ...
  // do smth with the serviceObject
  // ...
}
```

Now my question is: once the service implementation object is retrieved from the serviceTracker, there is no guarantee that it will be available (won't be removed) immediately after the null-check.

In other words, even within the if-cycle, the service object (serviceObj) may very well become null suddenly (if the corresponding service is unregistered)

Therefore we should always correct the code above like this:

```
ServiceInterface serviceObj = (ServiceInterface) serviceTracker.get();
if(serviceObj != null) {
 try {
  // ...
  // do smth with the serviceObject
  // ...
 } catch(Throwable th) {
  // a null-pointer exception may have occurred here!!
 }
}
```

Despite of this, no examples either in blogs (http://developers-blog.org/blog/default/2010/03/31/OSGI-Tutorial-How-to-use-ServiceTracker-to-get-Services) or books (Osgi In Action) talk about this requirement...

Am I right? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You're basically correct, however the question is whether to handle the exception in your own code or to allow it to bubble up the call stack to some kind of global handler.

Most OSGi developers that I know, and myself included, prefer the approach of allowing the exception to be thrown from this level. Catching exceptions at every point that they might occur leads to horribly bloated code.

In a sense, this goes to the heart of the debate between checked and unchecked exceptions.

Note one small correction: your reference variable `serviceObj` cannot become `null` after the null-check since it is a local variable, and other threads can never change the value of your local variables. However, as you deduced, the service reference can become defunct or inoperative. The chances of this happening are very small though if you have only just retrieved the reference from the tracker.

Comment: Re: null. You raised an interesting point about the null value issue. You're right: a local variable cannot be modified outside of its scope. Therefore the reference **will remain valid** until it gets out of scope. Now from what I've read about Osgi is that the reference we get by querying the service registry is nothing but the actual service implementation class (a java class). Therefore my code should always work and the exception in the if-cycle should never be thrown... what am I missing here??

Comment: PS: in my experience instead I did get a Null Pointer exception at least once

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. The service reference cannot become null but the service itself can become invalid. For example suppose the service represents the functionality of a device plugged into a USB port. The device is removed and very shortly afterwards the service will be unregistered etc. It's possible you could get a non-null reference to the service in that window, but it would fail if you called it, i.e. probably throw some wacky RuntimeExceptions. And that's okay because services are not meant to be 100% reliable.